# Setting a JPanel as a new JPanel from another class

Tags: java, swing, object, jpanel, cardlayout

I have a main Java GUI which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6CFR.png).

[image]

Basically there is a containerPanel which contains a cardPanel of cards (the right hand side), and then a GridLayout tabPanel on the left hand side.

The cardPanel contains many cards, one of which is a patientCard. This basically shows a JPanel which contains a JTable of patients.

I want to call code like:

```
cards = new CardLayout(); 
cardPanel = new JPanel();
containerPanel.add(cardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
cardPanel.setLayout(cards); 
cards.show(cardPanel, null);

patientsCard = new CSVTable();
cardPanel.add(patientsCard, "View Patients Panel");
```

And then call it to view via:

```
viewButton = new JButton("View Patients"); 
        tabsPanel.add(viewButton);
        viewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
            @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                cards.show(cardPanel,"View Patients Panel");
            } 
        });
```

Not that this code actually works for my registration panel which is not called from another class, but just like:

```
registrationCard = new JPanel()
```

**For some reason, this CSVTable panel when called from within the main GUI is not displaying at all, even if I do simple things like change the background. I have tried various steps including trying to include a new `Runnable` in `CSVTable` in the `try` method, changing the type of `patientCard` to type `CSVTable` object, changing the variables to `public`, putting the `CSVTable()` code in a `public static void main(String[] args) method` rather than a constructor.**

However, I know the CSVTable code works, because I tried creating a new swing application window via the windowbuilder with exactly the same code (but just with a JFrame included, not just a JPanel), and it runs and looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrZV4.png).

[image]

For info, here is my CSVTable() class code:

```
package hospitalsystem;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


public class CSVTable extends JPanel {

    /*
     * These are all static because I initially had these being referred to in a main class in CSVTable
     */
    public static String datafile;
    public static DefaultTableModel m;
    public static JPanel viewCard;
    public static FileReader fin;
    public static JScrollPane patientScrollPane;
    public static JTable patientTable; 
    public static Dimension patientPaneDimension;


     public DefaultTableModel createTableModel(Reader in, Vector<Object> headers) {
            DefaultTableModel model = null;
            Scanner s = null;
            Vector<Object> c;
            try {
                Vector<Vector<Object>> rows = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
                s = new Scanner(in);
                while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                    rows.add(new Vector<Object>(
                            Arrays.asList(s.nextLine().split("\\s*,\\s*", -1))));
                }
                if (headers == null) {
                    headers = rows.remove(0);
                    model = new DefaultTableModel(rows, headers);
                } else {
                    model = new DefaultTableModel(rows, headers);
                }
                return model;
            } finally {
                s.close();
            }
        }


    public CSVTable(){
        try {    
            datafile = "[my file location, kept private]";
            fin = new FileReader(datafile);
            m = createTableModel(fin, null);//This uses the method above
            System.out.println(m);
            viewCard = new JPanel();
            viewCard.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            viewCard.setBackground(Color.BLACK);//This was not being called at all
            patientTable = new JTable(m);
            patientTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(700, 70));
            patientTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
            patientScrollPane = new JScrollPane(patientTable);
            patientScrollPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            patientScrollPane.setOpaque(true);
            patientTable.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            viewCard.add(patientScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            viewCard.add(patientTable, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            viewCard.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: For better help, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't want to see your whole program, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem. You might very well solve the problem yourself by simply trying to isolate and expose the bug.

Comment: Unrelated problem with your CSVTable code: you are over-using and grossly misusing the `static` modifier as none of the fields of that class should be static. Please trust me on this. This is not likely the cause of your bug, but it's not going to help you in the long run.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the pointers ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have worked this out myself.

I was calling

`patientsCard = new CSVTable();`

Which should generate a new `JPanel` automatically. However, within the CSVTable class, I also generated a new JPanel via:

`viewCard = new JPanel();`

When I remove all references to `viewCard`, this new JPanel, in the CSVTable class, my panel correctly renders in the main GUI.

Hope this helps others in the same situation.